# Avoid overlapping factor loadings when using semplot function in R

Tags: r, plot, r-lavaan, factor-analysis, semplot

I have run a CFA in `lavaan` and am trying to plot the results in R. Data can be found here: https://github.com/pb865/EFBiasData/blob/main/EFdata.csv

Here is the CFA model code:

```
    CommonEF =~ Anntisaccade+StopSignal+Stroop+KeepTrack+LetterMem+SNback+NumberLetter+ColorShape+CategorySwitch 
    
    Update =~ b*KeepTrack+b*LetterMem+b*SNback
    
    Shifting =~ c*NumberLetter+c*ColorShape+c*CategorySwitch"
```

```
runcfa = cfa(model = cfamodel, data=data, std.lv=TRUE, orthogonal=TRUE)

summary(runcfa, standardized=TRUE, fit.measures=TRUE)
```

And here is my semPlot code:

```
semPaths(runcfa, whatLabels="std", intercepts=FALSE, style="lisrel",
         nCharNodes=0, 
         nCharEdges=0,
         curveAdjacent = TRUE,title=FALSE, layout="tree2",curvePivot=TRUE,
         edge.label.cex=2,
         sizeInt = 4, sizeLat = 7, sizeMan = 6, label.cex = 3, exoCov = FALSE)
```

Does anyone know how to stop the factor loadings from overlapping with each other? I've scoured the R documentation for semPlot and a bunch of posts on here and can't find an answer to this.